# How do use the font awsome icons one above another

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am new to the web development. I have a table ,

[image]

Now I am doing this using the

```
<th scope="col">Total Resumes<i className="fa fa-fw fa-sort sort-icon" onClick={() => props.sortCountAndScoreAscending('resumeCount')}></i></th>
```

Now, I tried with the two fa icons ,

```
<th scope="col">Technology
                <i className="fa fa-sort-asc sort-icon" onClick={(event) => props.sortAscending(event, 'technology')}>
                </i>
                <i className="fa fa-sort-desc sort-icon" onClick={(event) => props.sortAscending(event, 'technology')}>
                </i>
            </th>
```

But it gives me

[image]

So, How do get the one which is in the first image ?

After using the solution

[image]

what I have done is

```
<th>
 <div className="d-inline-flex flex-column">
      <i className="fa fa-angle-up sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type)}></i>
      <i className="fa fa-angle-down sort-icon" aria-hidden="true" onClick={() => props.sortData(props.type)}></i>
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: do you want only one icon or the icon in the second imagem equal the first?

Comment: I want to icons one is up and another is down.

Comment: in the third image did you apply a solution, which one? What do you want different from it?

Comment: The one given in the solution

Comment: it is adding too much of the space in it. And what I want is as per in the first image

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `<i>`s in a div and set the following styles to the div :

```
display: inline-flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: Try to apply `vertical-align: middle` to your `th`

Comment: Yes, I did this and I also have padding of 2 px to the i element.

Comment: What's the issue exactly ? The vertical alignement ?

Comment: Yes vertical alignment is the issue over here

Comment: ANd also the distance between the two icons is also a big

Comment: Vertical alignment :middle does not work, as my tr is a text-align :center

Answer (score 0):

After using the solution you need decrease the size of the icons, use css for this like this:

```
 <th scope="col">Technology
    <i className="icon-base fa fa-sort-asc sort-icon" onClick={(event) => props.sortAscending(event, 'technology')}></i>
    <i className="icon-base fa fa-sort-desc sort-icon" onClick={(event) => props.sortAscending(event, 'technology')}></i>
 </th>

.icon-base {
   height: 10px;
   width: 10px;
}
```

each icon will assume the size you set